# how to change char data type size if in column values there also

Tags: sql, oracle10g, database-administration

I am trying to change the size of `CHAR` data type.

```sql
create table test1(name char2(7));

select * from test1;   //table empty
```

then:

```sql
alter table test1 modify name char(4);
```

Changes the `CHAR` data type.

but:

```sql
create table test2(name char2(7));

insert into test2 values('aaa');
```

Then I try to change the size of `CHAR` data type:

```
alter table test2 modify name char(4);
```

But it returns the error:

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
alter table test modify name char(4)
Error report -
ORA-01441: cannot decrease column length because some value is too big
01441. 00000 -  "cannot decrease column length because some value is too big"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How to change the size of a `CHAR` data type?

Comment: `char2` pads the value with spaces.  Use `varchar2()`.

Answer (score 0):

A `CHAR` is a fixed-size string and if you try to put a shorter string into the column then it will be right-padded with spaces.

Either use `VARCHAR2` or create a second, shorter `CHAR` column and then insert a `SUBSTR` from the larger column.

## Option 1

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1( name CHAR(7) );
INSERT INTO test1 ( name ) VALUES ( '123' );
SELECT name, LENGTH( name ) FROM test1;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME    | LENGTH(NAME)
> :------ | -----------:
> 123     |            7
> ```

Then, if you do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test1 ADD ( name2 CHAR(4) );

UPDATE test1
SET name2 = SUBSTR( name, 1, 4 );

ALTER TABLE test1 DROP COLUMN name;
ALTER TABLE test1 RENAME COLUMN name2 TO name;
SELECT name, LENGTH( name ) FROM test1;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME | LENGTH(NAME)
> :--- | -----------:
> 123  |            4
> ```

## Option 2

Or, you can just use `VARCHAR2`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test2( name VARCHAR2(7) );
INSERT INTO test2 ( name ) VALUES ( '123' );
ALTER TABLE test2 MODIFY ( name VARCHAR2(4) );
```

Which, just works.

*db<>fddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f006dab768448fae6e1b09b8ace42dc)*